# How to use FormField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

**Code:**

```
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
      onPressed: () => _formKey.currentState.validate(),
    ),
    body: Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: FormField(
        builder: (state) => TextField(),
        validator: (string) {
          print(string); // always prints null
          return null;
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Whenever I try to validate the form, the `FormField` validator always returns `null`. I think I am using it incorrectly, can anyone show how to use `FormField` in above case?

---

**PS:**

I am not looking for `TextFormField`, I know my job can be done easily with it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs:

> builder → FormFieldBuilder
>
> Function that returns the widget representing this form field. It is passed the form field state as input, containing the current value and validation state of this field.

In your code, you are returning a `TextformField` as a widget representing this form field. If you want to validate then the only way it to use the `validate` property in the `TextFormField` widget:

```
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
      onPressed: () => _formKey.currentState.validate(),
    ),
    body: Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: FormField(
        builder: (state) => TextFormField(validator: (string) {
          print(string);
          return null;
        },),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormField-class.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what's the benefit of using `FormField` when you need to use `TextFormField`, second, you're not using `validator` of `FormField` in your solution.

Comment: I already said "In your code, you are returning a TextformField as a widget representing this form field. If you want to validate then the only way it to use the validate property in the TextFormField widget", `FormField` is just the parent class of `TextFormField`, the `validator` property in `TextFormField` is inherited from `FormField`, this is the same idea as the `Widget` class and the `StatefulWidget`

Comment: My mistake, when I was testing the code, I was using `TextField`, but when I wrote it as question on SO, I (by mistake) wrote `TextFormField`, I edited the post now. Could you please now tell me how to use `FormField` instead of `TextFormField` and have the validation running?

Answer (score -1):

change validator: to

```
validator: (string) {
     if (string == null) {
        return 'error message.';
     } else {
       return null;
     }
},
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my post `string` is always `null`, so there's no point of checking its nullability.

Comment: @iDecode you didn't mention that string is always null you mentioned validator always return null and the comment says print statemen always print null, in my solution if string is null the validator will return an error message and if not will go on

Comment: Take your time to read what the question was all about. In short, the `string` parameter in `validator` is always `null` as mentioned by me in the post and the question was how I can use `FormField` widget correctly.